# How to set Charging Profile while charging session is ongoing for Dynamic Load Balancing in OCPP

Tags: ocpp

I'm using ocpp-rpc library.

I am encountering an issue when trying to set a charging profile dynamically during an ongoing charging session. Specifically, after clearing an existing profile, I'm finding it challenging to set a new profile, which is crucial for my dynamic load-balancing logic.

Why might the setting of a new profile fail after clearing an existing one during an ongoing session? Are there any intricacies or restrictions in the OCPP standard or this library that I might be overlooking?

What I've tried:

1. Initial profile is being respected i.e. when making a RemoteStartTransactionrequest, whatever limit I give is being respected by the charger, and the expected limit is being applied.

```
{
  connectorId: 1,
  idTag: 'remote - 116 ',
  chargingProfile: {
    transactionId: 116,
    chargingProfileId: 1,
    stackLevel: 1,
    chargingProfilePurpose: 'TxProfile',
    chargingProfileKind: 'Relative',
    chargingSchedule:  {
       "chargingRateUnit": "A",
       "chargingSchedulePeriod": [
           {
               "startPeriod": 0,
               "limit": 16
           }
        ]
     }
  }
}
```

2. When trying to set a profile while charging to set a limit, the charger rejects the request.

```
{
            "connectorId": 1,
            "csChargingProfiles": {
                "chargingProfileId": 1,
                "transactionId": 154,
                "stackLevel": 1,
                "chargingProfilePurpose": "TxProfile",
                "chargingProfileKind": "Absolute",
                "chargingSchedule": {
                    "chargingRateUnit": "A",
                    "chargingSchedulePeriod": [
                        {
                            "startPeriod": 0,
                            "limit": 11
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

3. [ABB](https://new.abb.com/ev-charging/terra-ac-wallbox/terra-ac-wallbox-complying-with-iec-standards) chargers are failing to accept the default profile with this default request even before I start charging. 7.4kw 22kw.

```
{
    "connectorId": 1,
    "csChargingProfiles": {
        "chargingProfileId": 1,
        "stackLevel": 1,
        "chargingProfilePurpose": "TxDefaultProfile",
        "chargingProfileKind": "Relative",
        "chargingSchedule": {
            "chargingRateUnit": "A",
            "chargingSchedulePeriod": [
                {
                    "startPeriod": 0,
                    "limit": 14
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[Github Issue](https://github.com/mikuso/ocpp-rpc/issues/62)

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding duration to the above paylaod.
duration: 86400

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).